# Как перевести ассемблерную функцию в код для паскаля?

Tags: delphi, ассемблер, lazarus

Есть функция, написанная для Delphi, с ассемблерной вставкой, необходимо перевести ее в паскаль, самому это сделать не дает отсутствие глубоких знаний Ассемблера (познания оного остановились на Z80 в 90-х). Просто боюсь ошибиться: по моему пониманию, в сопроцессоре ведется обработка вещественных чисел (вталкивание, сравнение, умножение, нахождение синуса и условные переходы через основной процессор). Функция является частью построения сглаженных линий.

Прошу дать комментарии по алгоритму выполнения команд в функции, надеюсь по ним переведу их смысл в паскаль для Лазаруса.

```
function GetB(D,W: Double): byte;  
// Retuns the pixel byte value depending the distance 
// from the line relative to the line width
asm
    fld      W
    fsub     D
    fst      D
    fcomp    N3
    fstsw    ax
    sahf
    jb       @NotBig
    mov      al,$ff
    jmp      @End
  @NotBig:
    fld      D
    fcomp    N0
    fstsw    ax
    sahf
    jnb      @SinV
    xor      eax,eax
    jmp      @End
  @SinV:
    FLD      D
    FLD      N05
    FMUL
    FSIN
    FLD      st(0)
    FMUL
    FLD      N255
    FMUL
    FWAIT
    Push     esp
    FSUB     N04
    FISTP    dword ptr [esp]
    POP      eax
  @End:
end;
```

Comment: Я думаю справочника по ассемблеру будет вполне достаточно, чтобы справится с этой задачей самостоятельно. Ели у вас есть какой-то более конкретный вопрос по какой-то из инструкций?

Comment: Вопрос у меня конкретный, просто задан он был ГУРУ... Судя по всему, Вы не ГУРУ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько странный ассемблерный код, либо калька с другого кода, либо писался давно. Комментариев давать не буду - @kot-da-vinci абсолютно прав в том, что справочника по ассемблеру более, чем достаточно (я, к примеру, хоть раз в неделю, но читаю/пишу код на ассемблере, но я не помню все подробности по всем командам, и при этом достаточно иметь несколько PDF под рукой, чтобы вспомнить).

У вас не хватает определения ряда переменных, я считаю, что они double.

```
var
  N3, N0, N255, N04, n05:double;

function _GetB(D,W: Double): byte;
begin
   D:=W-D;
   if D >= N3 then
      begin
        Result:=255;
        Exit;
      end;
   if D < N0 then
     begin
       Result:=0;
       exit
     end;
    Result:=round(N255*sqr(sin(d*n05)) - n04);
end;
```

Comment: Подозреваю что N3, N0, N255, N04, n05 это константы: 3, 0, 255, 0.4 и 0.5.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Если это действительно константы, а не переменные, то тогда ассеммблерный код ещё более страннен :)

Comment: Спасибо большое, Виктор, Вы развеяли мои сомнения в сравнении регистров и выводе конечного результата, код конечно странный, так как смотрится глазами другого программиста, написан он еще в 2003 и взял я его вот отсюда: http://ez-j.com/. А по поводу справочников, то Вы и "Кот" конечно правы, но, увы, все это и так делается в свободное от основной работы время и, как всегда, времени на поднятие воспоминаний из дебрей справочников нет, что и заставило обратится к людям которым, на это времени не надо и опыта достаточно, чтобы оценить задачу одним взглядом. Еще раз большое спасибо и "Коту" тоже